# Собрать новый массив с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: массивы, php

Хотелось бы из этого:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00025
            [1] => 10000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00025
            [1] => 10100000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00025
            [1] => 10103000
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00025
            [1] => 99000000
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00025
            [1] => 99100000
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00026
            [1] => 10000000
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00026
            [1] => 10200000
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00026
            [1] => 10203000
        )
```

Получить такое (через ","):

```
Array
(
    [00025] => 10000000, 10100000, 10103000, 99000000, 99100000
    [00026] => 10000000, 10200000, 10203000
```

Подскажите кто чем знает? )))

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так:

```
$arr = Array( Array('00025', 10000000), Array('00025',10100000), Array('00026',10100000));
$newArr = Array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    if (!isset($newArr[$value[0]]))
        $newArr[$value[0]] = $value[1];
    else
        $newArr[$value[0]] .= ','.$value[1];
}

print_r($newArr);
```

Получим:

> Array ( [00025] => 10000000,10100000 [00026] => 10100000 )

Comment: Ура заработоло! Спасибо! )))

Comment: пожалуйста )